# docker push gives Failed to upload

Tags: docker

I am using docker on Ubuntu 12.04. I used docker 0.7.2 modified a container that I created with docker 0.7.1, and when I tried to commit the changes to the container, I got this `Failed to upload` error (tried twice):

```
avilella@ubuntu64:~/src/docker$ sudo docker push avilella/basespace-playground
The push refers to a repository [avilella/basespace-playground] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Pushing repository avilella/basespace-playground (1 tags)
5c7f024259a7: Image already pushed, skipping 
[...]
04869f04a8c9: Pushing 2.601 MB/16.55 MB 2m16s
[...]
2014/01/02 23:16:54 Failed to upload layer: Put https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/images/cdf6082e5d472d18c0540c43224f4c9b8d1264a2bb3c848a5b5e5a3b00efbf1a/layer: archive/tar: invalid tar header
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded Docker from 0.7.3 to 0.7.5 and this error stopped.

Answer (score 0):

ALSO POSTED ON GITHUB ISSUE:
I don't have the time to go through a lot of code now, if one of the dev's doesn't get on it I'll look into it later, but it appears to be an issue or change with the registry archive auto-detection settings, or tar file headers being used, probably changed in the new version you are using.

SEE SIMILAR ISSUE: 
http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2011-February/074737.html

If there is not too much work you did on the new layer, I would pull your previous docker push, from the registry, and redo the new layer work, then push it. You probably, did not pull from the registry, but built the new layer upon the last commit (locally) and that had different headers. It is probably a good idea, whenever you upgrade to push your work first, then upgrade, then pull and continue working from that pull as things like this can happen where headers and such are different in versions. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This got fixed in today's version of docker (obtained via apt-get in my case).